# Hadoop set supergroup does not work

Tags: hadoop

I set the property `dfs.permissions.supergroup = hadoop` in `hdfs-site.xml`

and the group hadoop has two users: `hadoop`, `postfix`

but,I got the log files as follows after I restarted my hadoop(hadoop-0.20.203.0)

```
2012-04-09 14:15:10,857 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: fsOwner=hadoop
2012-04-09 14:15:10,859 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: supergroup=hadoop
```

the `fsOwner` does not contain postfix :(

any insight appreciated

Answer (score 0):

can you check wheather the postfix is added to the hadoop group.

(just to reference, login to postfix user and type this:

## id postfix

UID, GID, USERNAME, GROUPNAME THE USER IN)

Comment: yeah, sure about that : uid=1002(postfix) gid=1000(hadoop)

Answer (score 0):

The fsOwner in log files only record the current login user who start the hadoop-hdfs-namenode daemon. If you use postfix to start hadoop-hdfs-namenode daemon, the fsOwner will be set postfix.